# Printing a string and variable in MIPS

Tags: string, assembly, printf, mips

Here's the C representation of what I'm trying to do in MIPS assembly:

```
printf ("x=%d\n", x);
```

I know that I can do a syscall to easily print x=  and I can also do a syscall to print the int x (which is stored in a register).  However, that prints them like this (let's say x is 5):

> x=
>
> 5

How can I make them print on the same line?

Comment: I'm running this is the MARS simulator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the Fibonacci.asm example: http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/Fibonacci.asm - it seems to be a good example of exactly what you need to do - look at the part near the `print:` label. It looks like you needs `syscall 4` for printing the `x =` part and `syscall 1` for printing the integer itself.

Answer (score 1):

Use a syscall for printing the `x=` which does not add a line feed.

What that syscall might be is system specific, and you are not mentioning anything about the system.

Answer (score 1):

If you print with two separate characters, 'x' and '=', you should avoid the newline problem.